# How to generate my grid coordinates based on a dynamic grid size in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to build up an array object given a fixed grid size, cell size, and center location.

Let's use 5x5 grid size, a cell size of 0.06, and 0,0 as the center. I'd like to build an array of cell objects that contain the boundaries of that given box.

[image: Example 5x5 with 0.06 spacing]

```
//So in this case.... Cell 0 would be 
x1:-0.18 , y1: 0.18 , x2: -0.12, y2: 0.18, x3: 0.18, y3: 0.12 ..... y4
// where x1 is top left X, y1 is top left Y, x2 is top right X, y2 is top right Y
```

I'd like to do something like this.. given grid size, cell spacing, and center

```
var grid_cells = 25;
var columns = 5;
var rows = 5;
var cell_spacing = 0.06;
var center = {x: 0, y: 0};
var gridcells = [];

for(var r= 0; r <= rows; r++){
  for (var c= 0; c <= rows; c++){

     var cell = {
        x1: top left corner X
        y1: top left corner Y
        ...
        ...
        y4: bottom right corner Y
     };
     gridcells.push(cell); 
  }
}
```

What's the formula to figure out the points in a box given the information? I know there's some equation i can plug it into. My end result should be 25 objects with the boundaries of each cell

Help me StackOverflow you're my only hope!

Answer (score 2):

So given:

```
var columns = 5;
var rows = 5;
var cell_spacing = 0.06;
var center = {x: 0, y: 0};
```

The total width of your grid will be:

```
var totalWidth = columns * cell_spacing;  // 5 * 0.06 = 0.3
var totalHeight = rows * cell_spacing;
```

To calculate the left most edge it's going to be:

```
var leftEdge = center.x - (totalWidth / 2); // 0 - (0.3 / 2) = -0.15;
```

So -0.15 is the x location of your first box and to calculate each box you just add `cell_spacing`. Same with height.

Note however, your diagram is wrong. If you start as -0.18 and add -0.6 then you right-most edge would be 0.12, not 0.18. And your center can't be at 0,0 because 0 is the left-edge of box 3.

Note your coordinates around the center box: -0.06,-0.06 to 0.06, 0.06. That's a difference of 0.12 in both directions.

So your loop might look something like this:

```
var topEdge = center.y - (totalHeight / 2);
for(var r= 0; r <= rows; r++){
  var leftEdge = center.x - (totalWidth / 2);
  for (var c= 0; c <= columns; c++){

     var cell = {
        x1: leftEdge,
        y1: topEdge,
        x2: leftEdge + cell_spacing,
        ...
        ...
        y4: topEdge + cell_spacing
     };
     leftEdge += cell_spacing;
     gridcells.push(cell); 
  }
  topEdge += cell_spacing;
}
```

Comment: This is partially there, however how do i use that topEdge formula to take in account where we are in the row/column loops?

Comment: @user176855: Not sure what you are asking there. I updated my answer because I left out that you obviously need to reset the `leftEdge` each time you move to a new row. The `topEdge` only gets updated at the end of each row.

Comment: I got it to work! Thanks very much, note that in your version gridcell[0][0] is the bottom left. Thanks!!!!! @Matt-Burland